# Excel day/month swapping when day less than or equal to 12

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, format

In excel I have code which transfers data from certain cells in the source sheet to the destination sheet. One of these is the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm. When it is transferred, however, it prints as mm/dd/yyyy.

My code to transfer the data is this.

```
Sub TransferDataAndSort()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet

' Set the source and destination sheets
    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Data")
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")

' Transfer new data and transpose
    destSheet.Range("B" & lastRow & ":F" & lastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(srcSheet.Range("C2:C6").Value)
```

In cell C6 I have the

```
NOW()
```

function to get the date and time. However, when the day is less than 13 it switches the day/month in the destination sheet.

I have noticed this only happens when the day is <=12. The formatting is the same in the whole column (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm), but not outputting that.

I have checked the formatting of the cells and it is correct in dd/mm/yyyy, and have checked the local settings and excel default settings of date/time and they are all correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Explicitly set the format of the cell based on your locale. The "swapping" happens because the default date format is US i.e. MM/DD/YYYY but once a day number goes over 12 it is obvious that it is non-US so it flips to DD/MM/YYYY. It's an age-old problem

Comment: E.g. `destSheet.Range("B" & lastRow & ":F" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` (warning - untested)
or, always use dates in YYYY-MM-DD format to overcome the probem entirely

Comment: @CHill60C neither of these solutions seem to work... thank you anyway

Comment: How is the data entered into the source sheet ?

Comment: The user manually enters information into cells C2:C5 then in C6 the cell just keeps the NOW() function entered permanently (this updates any time information is changed in the cells)

Comment: Try `Value2` instead of `Value` eg `destSheet.Range("B" & lastrow & ":F" & lastrow).Value2 = Application.Transpose(srcSheet.Range("C2:C6").Value2)`